# Copy a function reference without its properties

Tags: javascript, function

This may sound strange, but I want to make a copy of a function reference ignoring its members.
Take this example:

```
var a, b;

a = function(){ return "foo" };
a.x = "bar";

b = /* some magic here */;

a(); // foo
a.x; // bar

b(); // foo
b.x; // undefined
```

So, calling `a()` and `b()` must return "foo" as they are the same function.
Calling `a.x` and `b.x` must return different results, because `b` didn't copied `a` properties.

Is there anyway to do this?

**EDIT**:
To make it clear, I know that I can reference the whole function object like this:

```
a = function(){ return "foo" };
a.x = "bar";

b = a;
b(); // foo
b.x; // bar
```

But then, `b.x` is defined and equals to `"bar"`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand this, but could you do: `b = function(){ return a() };`?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, sadly no... I need a reference copy...

Comment: So you want to reference the function without referencing the function. I'm not too sure I see the reasons here.

Comment: @Aweary, a `for..in` loop will iterate over any object property. I want `b` to be callable object without properties to avoid such behavior (but that isn't my only motivation).

Comment: What's the problem with `b = function(){ return a(); }` then? You do get a reference copy indirectly (changes to `a()` will be reflected in `b()`.

Comment: Maybe you actually want `Object.definedProperty(a, 'x', {value: "bar"});`, which creates a non-enumerable property. You can't have "two" references to the same object where one reference behaves completely differently.

Comment: @Aweary, although this works in most cases (indirect reference), it won't work for me, because `a != b` (besides, it's another call in the stack).

Comment: You'll never be able to have `a == b` in this scenario. Object equality requires that both variables contain a reference to the exact object, so unless you're setting `a = b` / `b = a` it will always return `false`

Comment: @Aweary, you're absolutely right! What was I thinking? In this case, consider adding this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comments:

You'll never be able to have `a == b` in this scenario. Object equality requires that both variables contain a reference to the exact object, so unless you're setting `a = b` / `b = a` it will always return `false`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try a different approach, maybe `b = function() { return a.apply(this, arguments) };`, although this won't work in my current setup...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prototype to create separate `a` and `b` instances that inherit the same function. The instances can have their own unshared properties as well. For instance:

```
var a, b;

function zot() {};
zot.prototype.f = function(){ return "foo" };

a = new zot();
a.x = "bar";

b = new zot();

a.f(); // foo
a.x; // bar

b.f(); // foo
b.x; // undefined
```

Comment: You are not making use of prototypes though. `a.f` and `b.f` are two different function objects.

Comment: By using the `new` keyword, I am using `zot` as a prototype.

Comment: Nope, you are not. `zot` is a constructor function, it never is a prototype. `zot.prototype` becomes the prototype for every instance you create *with* `zot`.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's completely wrong, but it sure is not very detailed and uses the wrong terminology in some cases. The most important part about prototypes is the last section "Using the prototype Property" and it's very short. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript instead. Again, `a.f` and `b.f` are two different function objects in your case.

Comment: You can set prototype methods on constructors explicitly. Setting `zot.prototype.f` would set a prototypical method for all instances.

Comment: @Aweary: I saw your comment after I already made the same change :-). But thanks for the confirmation.